# Describe why converting a base class pointer to a derived class pointer is not allowed in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a vague idea of why this isn't allowed, but I'm looking for something more concrete.
I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that all of the methods in a base class might not necessarily be virtual.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derived class may define new methods and attributes, which are unknown in your baseclass. Java&Co will throw an exception in such circumstances.

In C++ you may (but rarely should) explicitly cast a pointer to the base-class to the derived one by a static-cast. It is undefined what happens, if the original pointer points to an object of the baseclass or another derived class.

See the awnser of Vlad Lazarenko for an example how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to describe why this is not allowed because it is, in fact, pretty much allowed.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Base {
    int b;
    explicit Base(int b) : b(b) {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int d;
    explicit Derived(int d) : Base(d), d(d+1) {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d(10);
    Base *b = &d;
    Derived *d2 = static_cast<Derived *>(b);

    printf("%d, %d\n", b->b, d2->d);
}
```

Comment: If the base class has no vtable (no virtual functions) but the derived class does this can fail because a pointer to base is not the same address as a pointer to derived. It also gets complicated with multiple base clases.